# Qual a classe gramatical e função sintática de "de Neumann"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, classe-gramatical

Suponha que um homem chamado John von Neumann tenha construído uma receita muito peculiar para se construir computadores. As pessoas dizem que essa receita é a Receita de Neumann.  Chama-se a esses tipos de computadores de Computadores de Neumann.

Na expressão "Computadores de Neumann", qual é a classe gramatical e função sintática do trecho "de Neumann"? (Que referência posso consultar para confirmar sua resposta?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe gramatical é a de Locução Adjetiva ([uma fonte](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucao-adjetiva/)).

A função sintática é a de Adjunto Adnominal:

pois "computador" é um substantivo concreto e "de Neumann" denota classe/tipo e torna o termo "computador" mais específico.

Fontes:

Base [LPeU](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/fdomd):

> Quando o núcleo for um substantivo concreto
>
> Substantivo concreto de raiz não verbal + estrutura 'DE + NOME', indicando especificidade, posse, matéria, origem – será Adjunto Adnominal:
>
> [...]
> livro da Maria (posse), etc.

[Mundo Educação](https://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/complemento-nominal-adjunto-adnominaltracos-distintivos.htm):

> A fuga do ladrão foi inevitável.
>
> - O complemento nominal jamais indica posse. Já o adjunto adnominal pode indicar posse, isto é, a fuga pertence a alguém - ao ladrão.